# Why doesn't addViewer work for non-Google accounts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I"m trying to build a script that would share a spreadsheet with an email when an email is added to another spreadsheet.

I found an example and slightly modified it so I now have a function that successfully shares a file  (it's triggered by any change in the email-containing spreadsheet).

```
//ssX -- object of spreadsheet to be shared 
function permissionsNemail(emailList, linkData, ssX){
  var badEmails = [];
  for(user in emailList){
    try{
      //Give permissions to edit. 
      ssX.addViewer(emailList[user][0]); 
 
    }catch(e){
      badEmails.push(emailList[user][0]);
    };
  };
  
  return badEmails;
};
```

This works just fine when an email is associated with a Google account (can be @gmail.com or custom-domained). However it doesn't work at all  when an email is not associated with Google (like for @yahoo.com etc). Couldn't find anything except for this https://support.google.com/a/answer/6033939 which doesn't help really. What bothers me is that when I manually share a file it can be any email, not just Google ones. Does anyone here have anything to suggest?

Answer (score 1):

### While you tecnically can share a file with a non-google account - the person with whom you share will not be able to open the file unless he signs in with a Google account

- Thus, it does not make sense to try and share a file with a person who does not have a Google account directly
- The only exception is if you provide to the person a share link and set the options to "Anyone on the internet with this link can view"
- In this case the file can be viewed in incognito mode and a sign in with Google is not required
- If this is what you want to do with Apps Script - instead of adding a viewer to the file you should [setSharing()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setsharingaccesstype,-permissiontype)

**Sample:**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var id = ss.getId();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
  var url = file.getUrl();
  GmailApp.sendEmail("userEmail", "Here is the view link", url);
}
```

UPDATE

If you do want to share a file with a non-google account in Apps Script, you can do it with the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) that is abed on the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive)

- After [enabling](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) the Advanced Drive Service in the Apps Script editor, you can use the method [Permissions: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/insert)

Sample how to do it in Apps Script:

```js
function myFunction2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var id = ss.getId();
  var resource = {
    "role": "reader",
    "type": "user",
    "value": "userEmail"
  }
  Drive.Permissions.insert(resource, id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! When you share a file with a non-Google email that person gets a link that yes, can be opened without singing in. The difference between the two links — this and the general 'anyone with a link can view' — is that the former can be revoked. So if I see suspicious activity I will simply revoke access from that non-Google email and their link will cease working.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior - you can only open the link without signing in if the sharing options are set to "Anyone on the internet with this link can view". Mind you that you can always revoke the access either through the UI or programamtically with `file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);`.

Comment: Set permission scheme to 'Only people added can open with this link' and try sharing the doc via UI. This is what you'll see:  https://monosnap.com/file/eOhIwk1YYxBn6F5l62vR1XDVOKQo4y
Revoking access via changing the file back to private will revoke access from all other 'incognito' users as well :(

Comment: Mind that it says "anyone holding this invitation will have access without signing in". But if this is ok for you  - I will update my answer on how to do this with Apps Script.

Comment: Yes exactly, they'll have access by their personal invitation link that can be revoked. Thank you so much for taking the time! I'll incorporate your snippet into my code and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Unfortunately, utilising Drive API didn't help :( I enabled Advanced Google services and switched from .addViewer to Permissions.insert but it works exactly the same: only shares the target file with Google accounts.

Comment: I tested it succesfully with non-Google accounts. Did you get any error message? Maybe there is some typo or empty space in `userEmail`?